# Linking FFTW to matlab using minGW

Tags: c, matlab, mingw, fftw

My goal is to mex come c code which uses the library FFTW.

```
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h> 
#include "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\fftw-3.3.5-dll64\fftw3.h"

void  mexFunction ( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])  
{
    int i, j, bw, bw2_1, size, size2_1, nrow, ncol;
    int data_is_real;
    int cutoff;
    int rank, howmany_rank;
    double *rresult, *iresult, *rdata, *idata;
    double *workspace, *weights;

    fftw_plan dctPlan;
    fftw_plan fftPlan;
    fftw_iodim dims[1], howmany_dims[1];

    bw = 2;
    weights = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 4 * bw);
    rdata = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 5 * bw);
    dctPlan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(2 * bw, weights, rdata, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
}
```

I'm currently using minGW and *not Visual C++*. If (from Matlab) I call

```
>>mex -c -LC:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\fftw-3.3.5-dll64 demo_fftw.c
```

it compiles correctly, but running

```
>> mex -LC:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\fftw-3.3.5-dll64 demo_fftw.c
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
Error using mex C:\Users\MPUTHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_200676192178726_4216\demo_fftw.obj:demo_fftw.c:(.text+0x40):undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_plan_r2r_1d'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think that the error is because although fftw_plan_r2r_1d is declared in fftw3.h, it is defined somewhere else where the linker can't find it. I know that if I'm using Visual C++, then the .lib files contain the definitions, but the the README only tells you to compile the lib's if you are using Visual C++, and says nothing about using mingw.

What's the equivalent of a .lib file for mingw? Do I still need .lib's? If so, how do I compile them?

I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I've looked around a bit and find lots of advice that works if you are using visual C++, but none concerning mingw.

Comment: looks like to need to link with the fftw lib. like `-lfftw` (providing the path where the library is located with `-L/path/to/lib`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So I do need to generate the corresponding library? How do I do this using MinGW?

Comment: on MinGW it would be a DLL or a .a file. The lib files are stubs AFAIR, you need DLLs anyway. You can use a binary distrib of fftw for windows, no need to rebuild it hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already made it possible for the compiler to see the FFTW include header file.

Now, you need to link with the actual FFTW code.

Fortunately, FFTW creators are merciful for Windows users and provided pre-built distros available here: http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

> We have created precompiled DLL files for FFTW 3.3.5 in single/double/long-double precision, along with the associated test programs. We hope that these are sufficient for most users, so that you need not worry about compiling FFTW
>
> These DLLs were created by us, cross-compiled from GNU/Linux using MinGW; the 64-bit version is possible thanks to the mingw-w64 project. You should be able to call them from any compiler.

So MinGW is fine. In your case I would do (untested):

```
mex -LC:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\fftw-3.3.5-dll64 demo_fftw.c libfftw3-3.dll
```

Comment: They are merciful indeed. That probably has something to do with why their libraries are so widely used. Running your command gives the error

    Error using mex
    Unknown file extension '.dll'.

Comment: yes, and this FFT library is just awesome. just make sure that your data orientation is good. Don't use stride != 1 as it generates a lot of cache misses.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out why your command wasn't working, but eventually I found a computer with Visual C++ installed, and your command worked (replacing .dll with .lib). Thanks for your help